# how to create query parser to parse query param in spring REST

Tags: spring, rest

My query parameter is like this:

```
q=name:abc+age:20+roleid:(23|45)|audeince:(23|24).Here + is for AND | is for OR
```

I have to accept this query param as it is into my spring controller and have to make query to solar to fetch the data.

￼

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class BooksController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(final HttpServletRequest request) {

  String params = requestParams.get("q")[0];
    //passing this string to make query in apache solar
}
}
```

I need to write a parser to split the param value to make a solar query.how to write a query parser to split the above url to make solar query satisfying OR AND condition.name:abc+age:20+roleid:(23|45)|audeince:(23|24) means create a solar query where name=abc and age=20 and roleid in (23,24) or audience in (23,24) .This way user sends query.

Eg:firstName:(abc|bcd)+lastName:abc+emailId:abc+dsID:abc|countryCd:US+audienceId:(123+678)

first using regex convert like this 
firstName:(abc|bcd)+  -----------segment1

lastName:abc+.............segment2

emailId:abc+.............segment3

dsID:abc|--------------segment4

countryCd:US+----------segment5

audienceId:(123+678)------segment 6;

like many segments may come in  the url

i have a class   called

class Queryobj{

private String  field;

private List value;

private String internalOperator;

private String externalOperator;

}

firstName:(abc|bcd)+ again using regex map Like this

field=firstName

value={abc,bcd}

internalOperator=|

externalOperator=+

like second segment  emailId:abc+

field=emailId

value=abc

internalOperator=null

externalOperator=+

same for other segments also .if there are n segments we have n objects.

After that add each object to Linked List.if internalOperator or externalOperator is null then leave it as null .How can I achieve that

Comment: Can you please post the Controller code stating what you have tried ?

Comment: What is the meaning of this string? What parts does it consist of? As long as we have to guess about the *meaning*, we can only answer with guesses about how to *parse* it.

Comment: ￼@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class BooksController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(final HttpServletRequest request) {

  String params = requestParams.get("q")[0];
    //passing this string to make query in service class
}
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question of you want to add code. Don't put code into a comment, it is very hard to read.

Comment: please look Lutz Horn or Gyanapriya and  please tell me

Comment: You can write your own query parser with Java grammer take help from below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35748/An-Introduction-to-JavaCC

Comment: is it possible with regular expression matching ManojP because need to complete within 2 days

Comment: If you need help in parsing this string you will have to tell us how it is constructed. What parts does it consist of? How can these parts be recognized? Do all parts always occur or are they optional?

Comment: there are lot of combinations firstName:abc+lastName:abc+emailId:abc+dsID:abc+countryCd:US| audienceId :(123+456) .firsatname:abc is one key value pair also we can have many key value pair separated by and (+) or (1) also inside value  (123+456) we may have + or |

Comment: please tell how to write a regular expression to split this string .Or any another solution.I want key value pair   to make query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern to get "key:value operator" segment

```
Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w]+:([\\w@.]+|\\([\\w|+@.]+\\))[+|]?");
```

Comment: please explain me detail  the code  i  can't understnd  it

Comment: I want a solution  which would extract key value pair  along with operators (and ,or) then put it in a data structure  so that it can be used to query  .Also operators  (and  ,or) satisfied across key value pairs

Comment: dknight can you help me

Comment: From your first example, I assume this query string is composed of following style:  q-> "key:values op"  key->[a-zA-z0-9] op-> [+|], values->[a-zA-Z_0-9] or ([a-zA-Z_0-9]). I think you can first match the pattern :(\w), then split the q string with operator '+' or '|'. I doubt why '+' exist in string :(123+456)?

Comment: + in string means age=123 and age=456

Comment: can you add the sample code to do it.=name:abc+age:20+roleid:(23+45)|audeince:(23|24)

Comment: i want a hash map to captain key value pairs  to be able to query.or any solution to  separate keys and values and operators between values and  also  operators between different keys and values.dknight please look into it

Comment: name:abc+age:20+roleid:(23+45)|audeince:(23|24) .query should be like this select * from  <solar> where name =abc and age=20 and (roleid=23 and roleid=45) or (audience  =23 or audience =24)

Comment: can you give a regular expression to split key value pair in the above

Comment: please provide a regular expression to spit the above url so that i can get key values as separated

Comment: How to you solve this string q=((age:(14,155)+name:dk)?

Comment: idea is using regular expression we separate everything as keys ,values ,operators and value operator .then crate class having 4 instance variables.([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\\s*(\\w+(?:,?\\w+\\s)*)  could u please check this regex .I am not able separate values having ().i will put code on top .please check

Comment: firstName:(abc|bcd)+lastNamedddd:abc+emailId:abc+dsID:abc|countryCd:US+audienceId:(123+678)take this as example .there is an object called query object having fileds string field,List<string> value and String external operator and string internaloperator.Take example of firstName:(abc|bcd)+ then that object must contain filed as firstname,value as  {123,678}  and external operator + and internal operator |  .if no operator then it can be null.same applies for all segments.emailId:abc+ next .segment.dknight can you help me it is urgent i am stuck

Comment: dknight if you need any clarification please tell me .it would be great help for me .please .i am really stuck

Comment: You add all test string cases and expected result in question. Or can you describe you problem string in LL(1)  grammar?

Comment: dknight could you please check question .I have updated my requirements.please

Comment: [\\w]+:([\\w]+|\\([\\w|+]+\\))") when i give abc@gmail.com it  separates  only abc

Comment: please change  the regular expression so that i can get email value fully dklink

Comment: is it passible to write that regex without using Or | \\([\\w|+@.]+\\))[+|]?  because we can use matcher.group(1)..(2) like that